# At what levels do heroes in Hearthstone earn gold cards?

Tags: hearthstone

As you level up a hero in Hearthstone you earn gold versions of that hero's basic cards. For example the Druid earns a gold copy of Healing Touch at levels 15 and 20.

[image: Normal Healing Touch]
[image: Gold Healing Touch]

What gold cards do heroes earn at which levels?

Comment: As of early December 2013, currently you get gold versions of the basic cards every 5 levels (at least 15,20,25,30).  This may change before game releases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The community over at Hearthpwn has compiled a list of [Leveling System Rewards](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/general-discussion/593-leveling-system-rewards) (which is too long to enumerate here). Additionally the article on [leveling in Hearthstone at Gamepedia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Level) provides insight.

Here are some interesting points to take away from the articles:

- Gold Cards are earned one at a time. Unlike the basic cards, which are earned in pairs.
- Heroes also earn golden versions of the basic set of Neutral cards.
- Class specific gold cards are earned between levels 11 - 49.
- Above level 50 golden basic neutral minion cards are awarded.
- To earn all gold neutral cards a player will have to level every hero to 60.
- Gold cards are earned at levels: 15, 20, 23, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 and 60.

Comment: What will happen if I skilled 15 and 20 before unlock all my heroes 20/20 unlocked? My mage already over 15, and Paladin over 20. None of them received golden cards, because of I didn't unlocked some heroes basic cards. Can I take those missing cards on lvl 15, and 20?

Comment: @GereltOd: Huh?  Don't you unlock all the hero's basic cards automatically by reaching level 10?

Comment: yes you should have all your basic cards unlocked for the given class when you reach level 10 with that class