# What are the benefits of leveling up my heros?

Tags: hearthstone

Leveling up to 10 gave me the complete set of 20 basic cards. Since then I only got one golden card that I already had the regular version of.

What exactly are the benefits of leveling up? Are there fixed or random rewards, and what exactly are those? Does the level have any further effects on the game besides the cards you get as rewards?

Answer (score 9):

You get golden basic cards at fixed levels up to level 60. But that's all. Those are class cards up to Level 50 and neutral cards afterward.

For a more details see: [At what levels do heroes in Hearthstone earn gold cards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143945/at-what-levels-do-heroes-in-hearthstone-earn-gold-cards?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Leveling up all heroes to 10 is heavily recommend for every player.

After max level has been reached by a hero, your hero turns golden. This feature was implemented in 
Patch [1.0.0.4944](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Patch_1.0.0.4944).

> Golden Heroes have been added and now can be unlocked after winning 500 Ranked games with a Hero! Track your progress on the deck selection screen in Ranked Mode.

Comment: Golden at max level is no longer true.

Comment: All the information in this answer is either irrelevant or outdated.  It should be deleted.