# How to obtain basic golden cards that are not class-specific?

Tags: hearthstone

To obtain the golden basic cards for a specific class I need to level the class, but what do I have to do to obtain golden versions of basic cards that are not class specific, since they cannot be crafted with dust?

Comment: Also leveling. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143945/20810

Comment: This is a duplicate (or actually part-of) the question linked in the previous comment. It asks about specific golden basic cards while the linked question asks about all golden basic cards and its answer is thus included in the answer to that other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden neutral cards are earned for reaching levels 51-60 in a class, 2 copies of 5 cards for each class. Each class unlocks different gold cards.

A full list can be found here: http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/general-discussion/593-leveling-system-rewards